# how do you express $(a + b)^{0.25}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ separately?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

how do you express $(a + b)^{0.25}$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ separately?  For instance $(2 + 4)^{0.25}= 1.5651$, but how would you solve$$(2 + x)^{0.25}= 1.5651$$for $x$?

Comment: Note that $(2+4)^{0.25}=\sqrt[4]6 \neq 1.5651$.  It is close, but not exact.

Comment: Maybe the problem wants to use the formula like : $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$ with c and functions of a and b?

Answer (score 3):

You can't in the general cases. The simplest way it can be written is $\sqrt[4]{a+b}$ or $(a+b)^{\frac{1}{4}}$.

To solve an equation like $$(2+x)^{\frac{1}{4}}=1.5651,$$
raise both sides of the equation to the $4$th power. You arrive at $$x=1.5651^{4}-2.$$

The idea in all cases such as this is removal of the radical by raising both sides of the equation to the power adequate to remove the radical. In general, $x^{\frac{1}{n}}=y$ would require us to raise both sides to the $n$th power to solve the equation for $x$.

Comment: You mean to the fourth power, not to the $3/4$ power.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. @JuliánAguirre

Answer (score 3):

This is [Isaac Newon's (generalized) binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem).

\begin{align}
(a+b)^{0.25} & = a^{0.25} + 0.25a^{0.25-1}b + \frac{(0.25)(0.25-1)}{2} a^{0.25-2}b^2 + {}
\\[12pt]
& {}+ \frac{(0.25)(0.25-1)(0.25-2)}{6} a^{0.25-3} b^3+ \cdots\cdots
\end{align}
This works if $|a|>|b|$.  If the inequality is reversed, then interchange the roles of $a$ and $b$.

(The denominators are the factorials $1,1,2,6,24,120,\ldots$ .